# Optimizing a geo search in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I'm searching for UK postcodes within a radius of a given postcode.  The query that I'm using looks like this:

```
SELECT *,
    earth_distance(ll_to_earth( {$lat}, {$lon} ), ll_to_earth(lat, lng)) as distance
FROM postcodes
WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth({$lat}, {$lon}), {$meterDistance}) @> ll_to_earth(lat, lng)
    AND earth_distance(ll_to_earth( {$lat}, {$lon} ), ll_to_earth(lat, lng)) <= {$meterDistance}
```

Where the {$variables} are replaced with the proper numeric values at runtime.

I have already created an index for ll_to_earth(lat, lng)) on my table.

I want to know if the Postgres parser is intelligent enough to calculate earth_distance(ll_to_earth( {$lat}, {$lon} ) only once or if it is going to be repeating the same calculation on every row.

Obviously if it is going to repeat the calculation on each row then I would like to find a way to optimize this (any suggestions?).

The reason that I have the AND clause is because I'm using earth_box and require a radius.  I do require the distance between the postcodes to be returned.

----- Update in response to query -----

It's PHP magic inserting the values before sending the query.  An example of the query is:

```
SELECT *,
   earth_distance(ll_to_earth( 51.66628422683990000, -0.61470728159074400 ), ll_to_earth(lat, lng)) as distance
FROM postcodes
WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(51.66628422683990000, -0.61470728159074400), 4828.02) @> ll_to_earth(lat, lng)
  AND earth_distance(ll_to_earth( 51.66628422683990000, -0.61470728159074400 ), ll_to_earth(lat, lng)) <= 4828.02
```

The EXPLAIN ANALYZE looks like this:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on postcodes  (cost=173.59..6777.31 rows=568 width=48) (actual time=20.785..210.522 rows=1202 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: ('(3950943.86394944, -47269.8036202945, 4998280.46727446),(3960599.90371891, -37613.763850828, 5007936.50704393)'::cube @> (ll_to_earth((lat)::double precision, (lng)::double precision))::cube)"
"  Filter: (sec_to_gc(cube_distance('(3955771.88383417, -42441.7837355612, 5003108.4871592)'::cube, (ll_to_earth((lat)::double precision, (lng)::double precision))::cube)) <= 4828.02::double precision)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 969"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on postcode_gis_index  (cost=0.00..173.45 rows=1704 width=0) (actual time=2.910..2.910 rows=2171 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ('(3950943.86394944, -47269.8036202945, 4998280.46727446),(3960599.90371891, -37613.763850828, 5007936.50704393)'::cube @> (ll_to_earth((lat)::double precision, (lng)::double precision))::cube)"
"Total runtime: 210.842 ms"
```

I have only really worked in mySQL before and I'm not sure how to interpret the analysis.  I have looked for documentation but it doesn't really help me to answer whether the common functions are being calculated repeatedly.

How would I structure the query so that I could generate earth_distance(ll_to_earth( 51.66628422683990000, -0.61470728159074400 ), ll_to_earth(lat, lng)) as a constant and calculate it just once?

Comment: The parser does not optimize your query, it's the optimizer ;)  Other than that,  a table definition complete with indexes and other ornaments is needed, alongside with an output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.  Also, how the values 'are replaced with the proper numeric values at runtime'?  Is this a prepared statement, some PHP magic or other?